# Passing a Visual C++ delegate to a native C++ class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, delegates, c++-cli

I have a native class which requires a function pointer in the constructor. I have tried searching the forums, but couldnt quite find what I was looking for.

The native class looks like this:

```
class NativeClass{
    NativeClass(std::string(*callback)(std::string args)){
    //native code goes here
    }
};
```

What is the best way of passing a delegate? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have already written two simple functions that flawlessly convert from managed String to unmaged std::string. I have no problem calling unmanged functions. What i'm struggling with is function pointer bit.

Comment: So does that mean that `string` here __does__ or __doesn't__ mean `std::string`?

Comment: I've edited and changed string to std::string. So yes, it **is** std::string. That's not the point. I can convert if need be. What i need help with is the delegate part.

Comment: That's not the preferred way to pass a callback in standard C++ either.  Better to use `std::function<std::string(std::string)>` to allow passing a functor containing state (with a functor you could easily keep a `gcroot<ManagedDelegateType^>` and call it with converted arguments).  But this should be solvable if you follow DavidHeffernan's advice.

Comment: @Ben : I was going under the assumption that the delegate would be used in some other .NET language (e.g. C#). You're right that if it's used only within the same C++/CLI assembly then it should work.

Comment: @ildjarn: will definately only be used in the same C++/CLI assembly

Comment: @ildjarn: The delegate is being used to pass a callback to native code.  From the delegate CLS-compliant methods can be called, including perhaps other delegates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getfunctionpointerfordelegate.aspx) to achieve this.

Note that this will return a function pointer that uses the `stdcall` calling convention. You can specify a different calling convention by using the `UnmanagedFunctionPointer` attribute on your delegate declaration.